# Convert class to derived class, without modifying it

Tags: c++

I am working with a set of classes `A`, `B`, ... These classes are independent except that they have one `method` in common. Now I want to combine these classes in a vector, to call `method` in one loop. It seems that the best solution is to make the classes derived classes from some `Parent` (see below).

Now the question is the following. I want to create a header-only library for each class (`a.h`, `b.h`, ...). There I want the classes to be completely independent. Only in the main module I want to 'attach' the classes to a `Parent` to be able to combine them in a vector. How do I do this? Or do I have to resort to a vector of `void*` pointers? Or is there another way to combine these classes in a vector?

---

### Classes in list: with parent/child paradigm

Here is what I have been able to do to combine the classes in the vector. Note I specifically want to avoid the parent/child paradigm in the class definitions. But I still want to combine them in a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Parent
{
public:
  virtual ~Parent(){};
  virtual void method(){};
};

class A : public Parent
{
public:
  A(){};
  ~A(){};
  void method(){};
};

class B : public Parent
{
public:
  B(){};
  ~B(){};
  void method(){};
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>> vec;

  vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Parent>(new A));
  vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Parent>(new A));
  vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Parent>(new B));

  for ( auto &i: vec )
    i->method();

  return 0;
}
```

Compile using e.g.

```
clang++ -std=c++14 main.cpp
```

Comment: No need to add superfluous inheritance. Try a vector of  [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Comment: The only way to "attach" a child class to a parent class is through inheritance in the source for the compiler to handle. If you make the `Parent` class *abstract* (by removing the destructor and making `method` a pure virtual function) the child classes are still pretty much "self contained".

Comment: @StoryTeller and then switch on the variant selector and use separate code to call A::foo, B::foo and C:: foo, and modify everything each time you add D to A,B, and C. We can do better than that.

Comment: @n.m. - That would depend on the nature of the set of types. The OP seems to have a closed set (although I may have misunderstood). Closed set polymorphism with variant is easy enough the implement.

Comment: @Tom, Like you see. There are many ways to achieve type erasure in C++, all under the same basic principle of uniting static polymorphism (tempaltes) with dynamic forms of polymorphism.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm genuinely impressed. By the variety of very good solutions, but also (once more) by StackOverflow!

Comment: @StoryTeller Suppose that I would want to use Boost (though considering the answers below it seems that I can avoid it). What do I do: `std::vector<boost::variant<A,B>> l; l.push_back(new A);` does not work...

Comment: @TomdeGeus - No need to `new`. Just `l.push_back(A{});`. We live in the world of values. No need for indirection.

Comment: @StoryTeller Cool thanks. Why is it that if I do `std::vector<boost::variant<A,B>> l; l.push_back(A{});` and put print statements in the constructor and the destructor that I get: `Aconstruct; Adestruct; Adestruct; Adestruct`?

Comment: @TomdeGeus - Depends on how you set it up. You should be able to call `boost::apply_visitor` on each member of the vector with a polymorhpic lambda. [Here's an example in C++17](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2d38682597510ae), where `std::variant` is in use instead. But the principle is the same.

Comment: @StoryTeller That example is great! Now I'll just have to wait for my compiler to support C++17 (in particular on our cluster, this might be quite a wait....)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a pseudocode, trivial details are omitted.

```
struct HolderBase
{
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template <class T>
struct Holder : HolderBase
{
  Holder(T* t) : t(t) {}
  T* t;
  void foo() { t->foo(); }
};

std::vector<HolderBase*> v { new Holder<A>(new A), new Holder<B>(new B) };
```

You can also have a variant of `Holder` that holds an object by value (and mix both variants in the same vector freely).

If you have a *single* method to call, there is a much simpler solution:

```
A a;
B b;
std::vector<std::function<void()> v { [](){a.foo();}, [](){b.foo();} };
```

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution based on type erasure, static member functions and pointers to `void` that doesn't make use of `virtual` at all (example code, far from being production-ready):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Erased
{
    using fn_type = void(*)(void *);

    template<typename T>
    static void proto(void *ptr) {
        static_cast<T*>(ptr)->method();
    }

    fn_type method;
    void *ptr;
};

struct A
{
  void method(){ std::cout << "A" << std::endl; };
};

struct B
{
  void method(){ std::cout << "B" << std::endl; };
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Erased> vec;

  vec.push_back(Erased{ &Erased::proto<A>, new A });
  vec.push_back(Erased{ &Erased::proto<B>, new B });

  for ( auto &erased: vec ) {
      erased.method(erased.ptr);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This can help to avoid using a common base class. See it on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JUNljQo8ZAiZ3zXf).

---

As mentioned in the comments, [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/239cdd32e5a38e63) is a slightly modified version that adds `create` and `invoke` methods to reduce the boilerplate for the users.

Comment: Nice, but do we need to specify Erased twice?

Comment: No, definitely, you can add another static function `create` to `Erased` and hide there all the details. Let me modify it this way.

Comment: I tried [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dda97a2dc2aaee3). And it's good enough for me :) Aggregate initialization for the win.

Comment: @StoryTeller [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/239cdd32e5a38e63) is a slightly modified version that reduces the boilerplate for the users.

Answer (score 2):

You want to erase the type of the objects and treat them uniformly, so naturally type erasure is the solution.

```
class with_method_t {
   struct model_t {
     virtual ~model_t() = default;
     virtual void call_method() = 0;
   };

   template<class C>
   class concept_t final : public model_t {
     C obj;
   public:
     concept_t(C const& c) : obj{c} {}
     concept_t(C&& c) : obj{std::move(c)} {}
     void call_method() override { obj.method(); }
   };

   std::unique_ptr<model_t> instance;
public:
   template<class C>
   with_method_t(C&& arg)
     : instance{std::make_unique<concept_t<C>>(std::forward<C>(arg))}
   {}

   void method() { instance->call_method(); }
};
```

Then have yourself a vector of `with_method_t` which is a value type. No raw dynamic allocation or de-allocation. The instance is build by forwarding the argument it receives into a small polymorphic container:

```
std::vector<with_method_t> vec;
vec.emplace_back(A{});
vec.emplace_back(B{});

for ( auto &i: vec )
  i.method();
```

Comment: I think you need to derive concept_t from model_t ;)

Comment: @n.m. - Yeah, details like that alwys kill my answers :)