# C++ list of multiple data types. Inheritance?

Tags: c++, types

I have a lot of different classes. However they are all guaranteed to have certain methods such as render() and activate().

My goal is to be able to store them all in 1 big list. Currently I have a big class called Container, and I do something like this to store the many objects I have.

```
class Container{
public:

  BUTTON * buttons;
  int buttons_len;

  DRAW_AREA * draw_areas;
  int draw_areas_len;

  Container(){
      // constructor
  }

  void render(){
      for( int i = 0; i < buttons_len; i++ )
          buttons[i].render();

      for( int i = 0; i < draw_areas_len; i++ )
          draw_areas[i].render();
  }

};
```

The problem with this is that every time I want to add a new datatype, I have to modify multiple areas and it will become unwieldy in the future. Whats a good way to do this ?

I have looked into using templates, and from what I saw, I cant store classes with different "template vars" in the same list.

Edit: forgot to mention that the render functions can be different render functions.

Edit 2:

I got what I wanted to work. Not sure how good it is in terms of "good code"

Here is an example:

```
// abstract class
class Base{
public:
    virtual void render() = 0;
};


class Button : public Base{
public:
    int y;

    Button(){
        y = 10;
    }

    void render(){
        std::cout << "BUTTONS " << y << "\n";
    }

};


class Draw_Area : public Base{
public:
    int x;

    Draw_Area(){
        x = 5;
    }

    void render(){
        std::cout << "DRAW AREA " << x << "\n";
    }

    void extra(){
        std::cout << "extra draw_area\n" << x << "\n";
    }
};



int main( int argc, char * * argv ){

    Base * test_1 = new Button();
    test_1->render();

    Base * test_2 = new Draw_Area();
    test_2->render();   


    Base * * test = new Base*[4];

    test[0] = new Button();
    test[1] = new Button();
    test[2] = new Draw_Area();
    test[3] = new Button();


    test[0]->render();
    test[1]->render();
    test[2]->render();
    test[3]->render();


    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for all the help ! the main 2 problems I had to deal with was making an abstract class to avoid object slicing, and storing the pointers to the classes and not the objects themselves in a list.

Comment: Not familiar with what that is. After a quick google search, what I understood was that it is basically creating a big class to encapsulate my many classes. Wouldn't I have to modify the base class at that point when i create a new data type ?

Comment: `BUTTON`, `DRAW_AREA` are different class types you have so far?

Comment: Why not making them inherit from the same interface?

Comment: If you just want to guarantee the existence of some method(s), setting up an interface would work well...

Comment: You should consider providing an example that show you class hierarchy and also how render is declared. The above code is not enough for us to be sure what you already understand and have done.

Comment: You are looking for [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44700815/817643), IMO.

Answer (score -1):

I have a working Game - Shader Engine that uses modern OpenGL. This project has many components that are integrated together. The one thing that is used is a series of `Manager Class` objects that they themselves are all Singleton objects:

I can not show you the full class but I'll show the enumeration of the Singleton base class that contains all the derived singleton types:

```
class Singleton {
public:
    // Number Of Items In Enum Type Must Match The Number
    // Of Items And Order Of Items Stored In s_aSingletons
    enum SingletonType {
        TYPE_LOGGER = 0, // MUST BE FIRST!
        TYPE_SETTINGS,
        TYPE_ENGINE,
        TYPE_ANIMATION_MANAGER,
        TYPE_SHADER_MANAGER,
        TYPE_ASSET_STORAGE,
        TYPE_AUDIO_MANAGER,
        TYPE_FONT_MANAGER,
        TYPE_BATCH_MANAGER,     
    }; // Type;

    // More code below
}; // Singleton
```

These are objects that we only want a single instance during the life of the application or the game.

---

Now as for your example and question the ones of importance in the list above that would pertain to what you are trying to achieve are:

- ShaderManager
- AssetStorage
- BatchManager

The others we can ignore since we aren't worried about `Audio`, `Fonts`, `Animations`, `Game Settings`, `The Main Game Engine` and the `Logger` although they are used through some of the objects listed above.

The 3 above are integrated in such a way that the `AssetStorage` class will hold containers of all objects to be rendered. The `AssetStorage` also holds other important stuff such as loaded textures, fonts, audio files, gui controls sprites, models, etc.. The purpose of the `AssetStorage` class is that it acts as a database that is responsible for managing all of the memory of these objects.

It is the `BatchManager's` responsibility to send all the vertex  data to be rendered, and this works based on a priority queue where that priority queue is determined by which `Batch` is the fullest or has the `highest priority` where that priority is based on `Z-Depth`. When the `BatchManager` is ready to send the vertex data such as attributes and uniforms, matrices etc, then it looks into the `ShaderManager` to see what Shader Technique to apply to the ready to be rendered vertices, and then it sets the attributes and uniforms according.

This is a very complex beast; this is also not the only way to do this as there are other methods, especially when you begin to start rendering 3D Terrains and you have to construct a Scene Graph, BSP, Voxels, Marching Cubes etc.

If you would like to learn more about the techniques described above you can visit [Marek Knows](http://www.MarekKnows.com) and follow his OpenGL video tutorial series. However the methods described above are using Modern OpenGL and you would have to follow through his earlier series that used Deprecated - Legacy OpenGL 1.0 for that is how he has his website set up.

---

What I can do is show you a small excerpt from the `Asset Storage's` header file so you can see the containers and methods of how this class "Stores" and "Manages" the memory of the Game's objects or "Assets".

**AssetStorage.h**

```
#ifndef ASSET_STORAGE_H
#define ASSET_STORAGE_H

#include "Singleton.h"
#include "CommonStructs.h"

namespace vmk {

class BaseMko;
class GuiElement;
enum GuiType;

struct Texture {
    bool        hasAlphaChannel;
    bool        generateMipMap;
    bool        wrapRepeat;
    unsigned    uWidth;
    unsigned    uHeight;
    TextureInfo::FilterQuality filterQuality;
    std::vector<unsigned char> vPixelData;

    Texture( TextureInfo::FilterQuality filterQualityIn, bool generateMipMapIn, bool wrapRepeatIn ) :
        hasAlphaChannel( false ),
        generateMipMap( generateMipMapIn ),
        wrapRepeat( wrapRepeatIn ),
        uWidth( 0 ),
        uHeight( 0 ),
        filterQuality( filterQualityIn )
    {}
}; // Texture

class AssetStorage sealed : public Singleton {
private:
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<BaseMko>>       MapMkoAssets;
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, TextureInfo>                    MapTextureInfos;
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<GuiElement>>    MapGuiAssets;

    MapMkoAssets    m_mkoAssets;
    MapTextureInfos m_textureInfos;
    MapGuiAssets    m_guiScreenAssets;
    MapGuiAssets    m_guiRenderableAssets;

    std::vector<std::string> m_vGuiForRemoval;

public:
    AssetStorage();
    virtual ~AssetStorage();

    static AssetStorage* const get();

    // Mko Objects
    BaseMko*    getMko( const std::string& strId ) const;
    void        add( BaseMko* pMko );
    bool        removeMko( const std::string& strId, bool removeTexture = false );
    void        showLoadedMkoObjects() const;

    // Texture Objects
    TextureInfo getTextureInfo( const std::string& strFilename ) const;
    TextureInfo add( const Texture& texture, const std::string& strFilename );
    bool        removeTextureInfo( const std::string& strFilename );
    bool        removeTextureInfo( unsigned uTextureId );
    void        showLoadedTextureInfo() const;

    // Gui Objects
    GuiElement* getGuiElement( const std::string& strId, GuiType type ) const;
    void        add( GuiElement* pGui, GuiType type );
    bool        removeGuiElement( const std::string& strId, bool removeTextures = false );
    template<typename T>
    bool        removeGuiElement( T* pGui, bool removeTextures = false );
    void        markGuiForRemoval( const std::string& strId );
    void        cleanOrphanedGuiObjects();
    void        showLoadedGuiObjects() const;

private:
    AssetStorage( const AssetStorage& c ); // Not Implemented
    AssetStorage& operator=( const AssetStorage& c ); // Not Implemented

    // Gui Objects
    GuiElement* getGuiElement( const std::string& strId, const MapGuiAssets& guiMap ) const;
    void        add( GuiElement* pGui, MapGuiAssets& guiMap );
    bool        removeGuiElement( const std::string& strId, MapGuiAssets& guiMap, bool removeTextures );
}; // AssetStorage

} // namespace vmk

#endif // ASSET_STORAGE_H
```

---

I can also show you the declarations of the `BatchManager` & `ShaderManager` classes, but I can not show you the ***Implementations*** of them.

**BatchManager.h**

```
#ifndef BATCH_MANAGER_H
#define BATCH_MANAGER_H

#include "Singleton.h"
#include "CommonStructs.h"

namespace vmk {

class Batch;

class BatchManager sealed : public Singleton {
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Batch>> m_vBatches;

    unsigned m_uNumBatches;
    unsigned m_uMaxNumVerticesPerBatch;

public:
    BatchManager( unsigned uNumBatches, unsigned uNumVerticesPerBatch );
    virtual ~BatchManager();

    static BatchManager* const get();

    void render( const std::vector<GuiVertex>& vVertices, const BatchConfig& config, const std::string& strId  );
    void emptyAll();

private:
    BatchManager( const BatchManager& c ); // Not Implemented
    BatchManager& operator=( const BatchManager& c ); // Not Implemented

    void emptyBatch( bool emptyAll, Batch* pBatchToEmpty );
    //void renderBatch( const std::vector<GuiVertex>& vVertices, const BatchConfig& confg );

}; // BatchManager

} // namespace vmk

#endif // BATCH_MANAGER_H
```

---

**ShaderManager.h**

```
#ifndef SHADER_MANAGER_H
#define SHADER_MANAGER_H

#include "Singleton.h"
#include "ShaderProgramSettings.h"

namespace vmk {

class ShaderManager sealed : public Singleton {
private:
    // Number Of Items In enum type Must Match The Number Of Items
    // Stored In s_aShaders And In InfoProgram::aShaderIndex
    enum ShaderType {
        TYPE_VERTEX = 0,
        TYPE_FRAGMENT,
    }; // ShaderType

    struct AttributeVariable{
        unsigned        uLocation;
        AttributeType   eType;
        int             iSize;

        AttributeVariable( AttributeType eTypeIn, unsigned uLocationIn );
    }; // AttributeVariable

    struct UniformVariable{
        unsigned        uLocation;
        UniformType     eType;

        UniformVariable( UniformType eTypeIn, unsigned uLocationIn );
    }; // UniformVariable

    typedef std::unordered_map<Attribute, AttributeVariable> MapAttributes;
    typedef std::unordered_map<Uniform, UniformVariable>     MapUniforms;

    struct InfoProgram{
        unsigned uId;
        std::array<unsigned, 2> aShaderIndex;

        MapAttributes mAttributes;
        MapUniforms   mUniforms;

        InfoProgram();
    }; // InfoProgram

    struct InfoShader{
        unsigned uId;
        std::string strFilename;

        InfoShader( int iOpenglSharedId, std::string strShaderFilename );
    }; // InfoShader

    typedef std::shared_ptr<InfoProgram>    SharedInfoProgram;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<InfoShader>     SharedInfoShader;
    typedef std::vector<SharedInfoProgram>  VectorInfoPrograms;
    typedef std::vector<SharedInfoShader>   VectorInfoShaders;

    VectorInfoPrograms                  m_vPrograms;
    std::array<VectorInfoShaders, 2>    m_avShaders;

    Program m_eEnabledShaderProgram;

    unsigned m_uActiveTextureNumber;

public:
    ShaderManager();
    virtual ~ShaderManager();

    static ShaderManager* const get();

    void create( ShaderProgramSettings& shaderProgramSettings );
    void enable( Program eShaderProgram );
    void enableAttribute( Attribute eShaderAttribute, unsigned strideBytes = 0, unsigned offsetBytes = 0, bool normalize = false ) const;
    void disableAttribute( Attribute eShaderAttribute ) const;
    void setAttribute( Attribute eShaderAttribute, const glm::vec4& v4Value ) const;
    void setUniform( Uniform eShaderUniform, const glm::mat4& m4Matrix ) const;
    void setUniform( Uniform eShaderUniform, const float fValue ) const;
    void setUniform( Uniform eShaderUniform, unsigned uValue ) const;
    void setUniform( Uniform eShaderUniform, bool bValue ) const;
    void setTexture( unsigned uTextureNumber, Uniform eSamplerUniform, int iTextureId );

private:
    ShaderManager( const ShaderManager& c ); // Not Implemented
    ShaderManager& operator=( const ShaderManager& c ); // Not Implemented

    unsigned initializeShader( ShaderType eType, const std::string& strShaderFilename );

    void processAttributes( unsigned uInfoProgramId, Program eShaderProgram, std::vector<ShaderProgramSettings::AttributeInfo>& vAttributes, MapAttributes& mAttributes ) const;
    void processUniforms( unsigned uInforProgramId, Program eShaderProgram, std::vector<ShaderProgramSettings::UniformInfo>& vUniforms, MapUniforms& mUniforms ) const;

    template<typename T>
    void setVertexAttribute( Attribute eShaderAttribute, const T* const pParam, bool bEnable, unsigned strideBytes, unsigned offsetBytes, bool normalize ) const;

    void setVertexAttribute( AttributeVariable attrib, const void* const pVoid, bool bEnable, unsigned strideBytes, unsigned offsetBytes, bool normalize ) const;
    void setVertexAttribute( AttributeVariable attrib, const float* p4Values, bool _x1_, unsigned _x2_, unsigned _x3_, bool _x4_ ) const;

}; // ShaderManager

#include "ShaderManager.inl"

} // namespace vmk

#endif // SHADER_MANAGER_H
```

---

As you can see this is quite a complex system of objects and the question that you are asking is a very broad question that can be done in many different ways all depending on your needs. I just presented this as to show a single concept of how one might achieve this.

As in the snippets of code above, you can see the different types of containers that are within the `AssetStorage` class, and then when you look in the `BatchManager` class you can see the prototypes of the functions to render the vertices which are done by `render()` and `emptyBatch()` and `emptyAll()`.

It is quite unwise to try and have every single "Object" have its own "Render" function. Each object should only have to worry about its `Attributes & Properties`. It should be the responsibility of the `GameEngine` to use these sets of classes to know when it is most efficient and time to render said vertices through a `Batch Process` and then applying the appropriate shading or color techniques.

Comment: I see, thank you, this is very helpful insight. I am not really making a game, but I'm trying to make an app to help me with my classes. A lot of the same logic still applies tho... Related to what you said about objects containing only attributes, How do I go about letting the engine figure out what sort of object to draw ? I imagine the objects would store some type of ID ? therefore when I decide to make a new type of object, I would have to modify the main code. My goal is to make it more modular. Only modify the new code and not have to change too much in the main driving code.

Comment: If you are familiar, I am thinking along the lines of what Blender 3D does. If you download a plugin from the Internet, you run a python script and import the plugin, suddenly the plugin is supported and now you can see all the buttons and such. How does big software like that make it self modular enough to allow for such actions ?

Comment: @suli Well to do something like that what you would need to do is create a base object that all "render" type objects will inherit from. Then the tough part would be to write a parser that parses a binary file to load or construct the objects to be rendered. Now as to when you want to render them you might have to adapt to another class that acts as a scheduler or an event manager and retrieves the objects by id from your storage or container class. Note: I did not mention it above in my answer but this engine above also allows for... uses multithreading.

Comment: My original plan was to have the program parse objects from an XML document. This would force me to have to re-compile the program every time I add a "module". Since you mentioned parsing a binary file, does that mean I can leave my program compiled and just compile the "module" I want to add ?

Comment: With a binary parser, you should be able to just save the modified binary in a hex editor and then just re-run you application. This is the same concept as how shaders such as HLSL or GLSL works within DirectX or OpenGL. You do not have to rebuild or recompile the program, just save the changes to the file and the program will run. The parser should be designed to accept keywords or tokens and know how to parse the expected data to make your data structures internally.

Answer (score -2):

If every class has a `render()` function and you want to call all of them with a single command, then you can do this.

```
class outer
{
public:
    outer(); // Constructor.
    render();

private:
    other_class1 in_class1;
    other_class2 in_class2;
};

outer::render()
{
    in_class1.render();
    in_class2.render();
    // For all other member classes.
}
```

You can then just call the render function of the outer class `outer.render()` which calls all of the member classes' `render()` functions.

Comment: Oh. Sorry, the render functions can be different in some cases. There is a default one that I can override. For example, they all render a square by default, then when I create the  button class, it can inherit from the base, then I override it to make it render a button.

Comment: So you have a default class that has a default `render()` function(that renders a square), and when you inherit it you change it to the shape you want. And then what exactly do you want to store in a list? The custom objects that you create?

Comment: wait. sorry. I misunderstood, this allows for unique render functions... however I would still need to modify many different places when I add a new datatype. And would still require the loops when I make them a list in the class outer

Comment: I want to be able to render all the BUTTON classes and DRAW_AREA classes without having to make a custom loop for each.

Comment: As it stands right now, when I create a new class, IMAGE for example. I will have to create a new list of IMAGE objects and then loop over them in the render function. It seemed repetitive, so I figured there is a better way.

Comment: Will each loop have the same parameters but for a different object? if yes then you can have it as a template function with a call-by-reference parameter, and run that function for each different objects.

Comment: yeah, each loop is gonna be the exact same loop. However the number of BUTTON objects and the number of DRAW_AREA objects can be different.

Comment: Have the render function as a template ?

Comment: You want a single loop for both BUTTON and DRAW_AREA or you want 2 loops: one for each of those types and their respective derived classes? Usually, you have a class hierarchy and you need a single loop. By the way, I would recommend you to use STL containers if you are doing your own framework. In that case, you might consider `std::unique_ptr` too. Uppercase class name is not following usual naming conventions. If I would do my own framework, I would also consider the visitor framework for some operations.

Comment: You can also use a linked list to to store your objects, so going through the in the `render()` functions only requires a single loop which runs until you hit the end of the list. To add to the linked list you can have an `add()` function.

Comment: Have you considered a class hierarchy and **virtual** functions? Or you don't have any idea about object-oriented programming? Assuming that you are doing a library that may have 20 components, it would not make much sense to write 20 lists. And also, in UI you probably want to define order according to navigation order and/or z-order.

Comment: I want a single loop both. Yea I am working on making my code more readable. I fell into bad habits when I started and haven't changed them yet :/ Anyways, how would unique_ptr help ? would I be making a list of unique_ptr objects ?

Comment: Ah ! yea... I kinda forgot about the Z-index. But everything is being drawn using opengl and there is depth testing enabled.

Comment: virtual functions ?

Comment: Oh, I see, I google it. Yes that may work, however I had some issues when I thought about it

Comment: `unique_ptr` can help manage memory... but the main thing is that you should use virtual functions for `render` and `activate` and the list should be list of the base class pointer (or smart pointer).

Comment: The derived classes can be much bigger in size that the base class. In order to make it work, I need a list of base class right ?

Comment: therefore when I allocate memory to add my objects to the list, I would need to allocate more depending on which object it is.

Comment: nvm. After thinking it over, It occured to me that I am storing pointers and not the actual object in the list.

Comment: @Phil1970 doesn't he already use virtual functions? How can he override the default `render()` function from square to a button?

Comment: At this point, you should try to follow some tutorials... on how to use virtual functions.

Comment: So to make it work, I can create a list of base_class objects. Then say to add a button, I would pass the memory adress of the button and then add that to the end of the list for example ?

Comment: I use virtual functions in my button class. It derrives from base, in order for me to have a guarantee that the functions I want are there.

Comment: Exactly that's what I was thinking.

Comment: It must be a list of pointers as you want to be able to store different object types and they might not have all the same size. And given that, you might consider using some smart pointers and write modern C++ code... if you start a new framework. But before doing that, you might want to check that no appropriate framework exists.

Comment: Also why was my answer voted down? So I can improve my answers

Comment: There are many frameworks that would satisfy my current project, such as QT. However I always felt bad when using such frameworks as I am unable to make stuff that are that modular and could be used for a huge amount of different things. So I was attempting to not rely on them.

Comment: I'll try storing them as a list of base classes with ptrs to derived classes

Comment: I'm saying whoever did... I just want to improve my answers

Comment: This is a horribly naive, terribly inefficient suggestion. Explaining why would take [a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1).